# the unicode gets inserted in database through query in phpmyadmin bt doesnt gets inserted through php (CI)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, unicode

i am building a nepali site ...
it works fine with browser...now i am trying to insert the words in mysql database ..first i tried by changing collation to `UTF-8_general_ci`..It didn't work..after doing hours of google i found a way ..

In the file `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/dbi/mysqli.dbi.lib.php` at the end of function PMA_DBI_connect() just before the return statement I added:

```
mysqli_query($link, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS =latin1;");
mysqli_query($link, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT =latin1;");
```

that worked in phpmyadmin when i did a small query..it gets inserted in the table with nepali words..

bt when i tried simply from php (CI ) though generating last_query()..
its doesnt get insert in table...the view i can get is ?????? where the nepali words should be...

note : my last_query generates

```
INSERT INTO `scheme` ( `functioning`) VALUES ( 'बन्द भएको ') ..
```

Comment: the question was asked before ..i did get the solution from there...bt i still am getting problem while simply inserting from php..

Comment: if i copy and paste that code in phpmyadmin it works though..

Comment: You left out `character_set_connection`.